# Typescript and Map returning error message

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dictionary

I have 2 interfaces that have the following properties

```
export interface parent{
   fName: string;
   addresses: Array<address>;
}

export interface address{
   street: string;
   city: string;
   state: string;
   zip: string;
}
```

In my code I load the parent class and the address properties from JSON.

When I try to retrieve the array of "street" properties, I use the following code.

var father = parent;
var streets = father.map(x=>x.street);

I am receiving an error stating father.map is not a function.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Read your own code again. Carefully this time. The `parent` interface isn't an array. And it doesn't have a `street` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to write `father.addresses.map(x=>x.street);` since the array is the addresses property